# Why is the .so file on Amazon Linux 5 times larger than on OS X?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, numpy, lambda

I'm attempting to put a project depending on `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas` and `scikit-learn` onto AWS Lambda, but am having trouble with the large `.so` files compiled on Linux. The total package size exceeds 320MB when compiled on Linux, whereas it is only 215MB on OS X.

(`scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.so` is 40MB on Linux, whereas it is less than 5MB on OSX, for example.)

Two questions:

1) Why is the file size so different between AML and OS X?

2) Can I just store these `.so` files in S3 and download them at runtime in my Lambda function?

Comment: I think it contains debugging informations. Try `strip scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.so`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation. @Ipor Sircer already commented about why it's bigger, so I want to share how to reduce the size. So, you might need to read the following:

https://serverlesscode.com/post/deploy-scikitlearn-on-lamba/

However, this article was not enough to solve this problem for me. Additionally, you need to avoid using pre-compiled packages with wheel, which is in the following link:

https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda/pull/3/files

Then, you will get smaller one for your lambda function.